# Considering the "Data Type" of a function in C?

Tags: c

I am going to be pretty vague about this and I am sorry. This is homework assignment I am trying to learn something so don't really want the answer but rather an explanation. The question is

```
  What is the datatype of thisThing
```

This is not the actual code but a similar example

```
  int* (*thisThing[])(int*, int*) = {someFunction1, someFunction2}
```

From what I understand the "datatype" of thisThing is simply an int. However I have never seen a function return type being called a "data type". Is there a reason for this? I know that have pointers to functions in C; are those pointers no different from variable pointers? Any explanation is well appreciated!

Comment: i can answer your question, but your education is more important than some useless REP. You should find this thing out by yourself. any standard book on C should explain this statement.consider reading this document http://www.cs.princeton.edu/courses/archive/fall05/cos217/lectures/08FuncPointerADT.pdf then ask what part of the statement you don't understand.

Comment: Lol, I wish that there were better resources online and cheaper books.

Comment: Check out [this translator](http://cdecl.org/?q=int%2A%20(%2AthisThing[])(int%2A,%20int%2A)). Read about "right-left rule".

Comment: This [site](http://cdecl.org/) might be useful for you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> the "datatype" of thisThing is simply an int

It's actually an array of function pointers where the pointed-to functions are:

```
int *fun(int *, int *);
```

You should look into the [spiral rule](http://c-faq.com/decl/spiral.anderson.html).

Comment: thanks for the splendid link. it seems like a simplified version of the section named complicated declarations from chapter 5 of K&R. its a shame that there was no SF when i took the C course in my first year of university (2006)

Answer (score 0):

thisThing is an array of pointer to a (function taking two pointer to integers as arguments and returning a pointer to integer). You may pl.read the chapter of complicated declarations from "K&R" C book.

Answer (score 0):

Variable `a` is an `int`:

```
int a;
```

Variable `b` in an array of `int`:

```
int b[] = {3, 4};
```

Variable `c` is a pointer to `int`:

```
int *c = &a;
```

You can also compose types, for instance, `d` is an array of pointers to `int`:

```
int *d[] = {c, b}
```

Variable `e` is a pointer to a function returning `int` and taking a pointer to `int` as single parameter:

```
int (*e)(int*);
```

Thus, what is the type of `thisThing` ? Clearly is is not simply `int`...

```
int* (*thisThing[])(int*, int*) = {someFunction1, someFunction2}
```

Answer (score 0):

"Datatype" is not a term used in the C standard; the correct term is "type".

In your case, given a value declared as `int* (*thisThing[])(int*, int*)` you can see that it can be called as: `int *result = (*thisThing[0])((int *)0, (int *)0)`, so the name of its type is *unspecified-length array of pointer to function taking (pointer-to-int, pointer-to-int) and returning pointer-to-int*.

Pointers to functions are *similar to* but *different from* pointers to data; importantly, they are not interchangeable and e.g. you *cannot* cast a function pointer to `void *` (whereas you can do that with any data pointer).  This is to ensure that your program runs on a platform where function pointers and data pointers have different representations.